# Matching two values in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^auth_token= %{QUERY_STRING} ^ref
```

and same with if not match

I am trying redirect of this condition matche`, otherwise not, I have googled all lot and search here too but nothing found yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 2 RewriteCond lines like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^auth_token=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ref
```

For negating use negation sign:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^auth_token=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^ref
```

Comment: Thanx, but I need to match the cookie auth_token=yes, with incoming URL Query Sring with .php?auth_token=yes, if they both not match then redirect to somewhere, I tried this but not working, RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^%{QUERY_STRING}

Comment: You cannot use `%{QUERY_STRING}` on the RHS of RewriteCond line